# Solid State Phonons at the edge of Brillion zone

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, integration, crystals, phonons

Bose-Einstein statistics tell us that the number of phonons with energy k at temperature
T via the bose einstein distribution.

My question is regarding phonons in the low energy regime.
My notes state the following:

[image]

But then later on says as follows:

[image]

My confusion is regarding the limits in the  second half. Why is it the limit goes from 0 to infinity when we were told to integrate along the Brillion zone in the boxed formula?

Answer (score 0):

In the case where $k_B T \ll \hbar \omega_D$, it doesn't matter because the principal contribution to the integral comes from near $k=0$. (And, in fact, the approximation $\epsilon_{\textbf{k}} \approx vk$ holds only near $k=0$ as well).